# Make the number to start from 1 if it is greater than 12 with PHP

Tags: php, date, date-conversion

I am trying to convert English Date with Nepali. I have done the following so far:

```
function nepaliYear($year){
$year = date('Y', strtotime($year)) + 56;
$month = date('m', strtotime($year)) + 8;
$days = date('d', strtotime($year)) + 15;
if($month > 12){
    $year = $year + 1;
    $month = date('H', strtotime($month));  //need help here
}
return $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$days;
```

}

I want the number to continue from 1 if the month is greater than 12. Suppose this month is July which is 7 and if I do 7+8 it gives 15. How to make month to 03? I tried to achieve this with `H` in the `date` function as the hours will be in 12 hours.

I hope you understood my question.  Will be ready add an explanation if asked. Thank you.

Comment: Just do `$month = $month - 12;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a simple solution that you can do.

```
if($month > 12){
   $year = $year + 1;
   $month = $month - 12;  
}
```

Since you have asked about converting the days in the comment section,

You know that there are leap years (February has 29 days sometimes). And for example July and August have 31 days. You can't say generally "convert 144 days to months" because it's different for every month.

For ex:

Lets imagine you need to convert 94 days into months.

```
<?php
$start_date = new DateTime(date("Y/m/d"));
$end_date = new DateTime(date("Y/m/d",strtotime("+94")));
$date_diff = date_diff($start_date,$end_date);
echo "$date_diff->m months $dd->d days";
?>
```

for `start_date` you can use a specific date. also for `end_date` this is the correct way, so every leap year and everything is observed!

Comment: hahaha! Sometimes we miss the smallest and the simplest things XD.If this was helpful  accepting the answer would be highly appreciated since it will help to increase my reputation points

Comment: The function will do my work but what if I want to get days also? Just curious. There may be 32 days sometimes.

Comment: @Gaurav I have updated the answer including getting days

Comment: @Gaurav .If this was helpful accepting the answer would be highly appreciated since it will help to increase my reputation points.

Comment: Sorry I remembered to upvote but forgot to accept the answer!